# Take Data From Oracle to Cassandra in every day

Tags: oracle, cassandra, migration, etl, sqoop

We want to take tables from Oracle to Cassandra every day. Because tables is updated in Oracle everyday. So when i searched this , i find these options:

- Extract oracle tables as a file , then write Cassandra
- Using sqoop to get tables from oracle, write Map Reduce job and insert into Cassandra ?

I am not sure which way is the  appropriate  ? Also is there another options ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Extracting oracle tables as a file and then writing to Cassandra manually everyday can be tiresome process unless if you are scheduling a cron job. I have tried this before, but if the process fails then logging it might be an issue. If you are using this process and exporting to CSV and trying to write to cassandra then I would suggest using cassandra bulk loader (https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader)

**Option 2**
I haven't worked with this, so can't speak about this.

**Option 3 (I use this)**
I use an open source tool, Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) (https://community.hitachivantara.com/docs/DOC-1009855-data-integration-kettle) to solve this problem. It's fairly a simple process 
[spoon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWtr0.png). You can automate this process by using a carte server (spoon server) which has logging capabilities as well as automatic restarting if the process failed in between.

Let me know if you found any other solution that worked for you.